Adding information to a single specific column in postgresql - after completing the other columns
I am creating an airbnb database datamart. I am using postgresql in the terminal. During the creation I would generate data via chatgpt to create 20 rows for each table. however, when creating the table I was unable to add some columns as foreign keys, as the original tables had not been created yet. After creating the new column in my table, I need to add new information to the attributes. How can I go about doing this?
Thanks
Im trying to insert information into the new attribute column that I added (guestinfo to profile table) but doing the following sql statement:
INSERT INTO profile (guestinfo) VALUES (5764);

...
It gives the following error:

ERROR:  null value in column "userid" of relation "profile" violates
not-null constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null, null,
null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 4785).

I want to be able to add information to the new attribute

Please provide the full sql, start to finish which is failing along with each table's DDL. It's not clear that the failure has anything to do with foreign keys as you can reproduce with a single table and a single record: https://dbfiddle.uk/JJOfy6rf

From the description, it seems that the row has already been inserted and what you want to do is to use UPDATE to set the value of the column in the existing row.

That was exactly it, thank you @JohnH !
